# Acidic KMnO4 oxidizes H2S to S. Why doesn't the oxidation proceed further to sulfur oxide, sulfur dioxide or sulfur trioxide?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, titration

I have some idea about the question. I think it has to do with oxidation/reduction potentials but I am not able to find any resource for the exact values or how to make sense of them in this context. Any reference would be appreciated.

Comment: The Chemistry SE  site policy recommends to use just plain text for the question titles, for indexing/searching reasons.

Comment: Instead of writing e.g. H_3PO_3 in MathJax, write e.g.  \ce{H3PO3 + 2 KOH -> 2 H2O + K2HPO3}. \ce{} invokes [mhchem](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here/88)   MathJax extension. It additionally uses expected upright font. See $$\ce{H3PO3 + 2 KOH -> 2 H2O + K2HPO3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the reaction can further proceed to sulfur dioxide and sulfur trioxide, but only appears for certain, per my research, to occur in alkaline conditions.

Here is [a supporting opinion](http://www.h2o2.com/products-and-services/us-peroxide-technologies.aspx?pid=117&name=Potassium-Permanganate) to this effect, which cites the corresponding reaction in alkaline conditions as:

> $\ce{3 S(2-) + 8 KMnO4 → 3 SO4(2-) + 8 MnO2 }$

that implies the further conversion of $\ce{S}$ to $\ce{SO2}$ to $\ce{SO3}$, which in alkaline conditions is represented by sulfate formation.

Note, the cited source notes only in acidic conditions, to quote:

> Neutral-Acid pH:
> $\ce{3 H2S + 2 KMnO4 → 3S + 2 MnO2 }$

[Wikipedia on KMnO4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_permanganate) supports this pH effect, to quote:

> The Mn-containing products from redox reactions depend on the pH. Acidic solutions of permanganate are reduced to the faintly pink manganese(II) ion (Mn2+) and water. In neutral solution, permanganate is only reduced by three electrons to give manganese dioxide (MnO2), wherein manganese is in a +4 oxidation state.

Interestingly, the corresponding reaction replacing KMnO4 with either H2O2 or HOCl, can results in $\ce{SO2}$, ..., in acidic conditions.

Comment: Thank you Ajkoer for your answer. It is very informative and an interesting read. Unfortunately (or fortunately) it challenges my knowledge. You have said the following things that seem confusing:  

1. Although $MnO_4$ is a weaker oxidizing agent in alkaline conditions, it is still able to turn $S$ to $SO_2$ and $SO_3$. 

2. Adding peroxide or hypochloric acid works the other way (by making the solution even more oxidizing) to obtain $SO_2$ or $SO_3$.

I checked out the references and indeed your argument is in agreement with them. I think something more interesting is happening.

Comment: I wonder if it is the enthalpy of salt formation/solvation that pushes the S to Sulphate form in alkaline conditions.